# Most efficient way to compare two List<T>

Tags: c#, performance

I'm trying to compare two lists. Here's the extension method I'm trying to use:

```
public static bool EqualsAll<T>(this IList<T> a, IList<T> b)
{
    if (a == null || b == null)
        return (a == null && b == null);

    if (a.Count != b.Count)
        return false;

    EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!comparer.Equals(a[i], b[i]))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I've already asked this question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104779/checking-two-lists-for-equal-items#104779). But I need more information about that. the answerer said that It's better to use [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) instead of `for` loop.

Now my question is that which one of two approaches is the most efficient way for comparing two `List<T>`?

Comment: [Horses...](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I commend you for the first condition check and how you evaluate the return. That's efficiently syntaxed.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Maybe I should have change the title.

Comment: The problem is not the title. The problem is that it's very easy to benchmark code yourself, while here you'll only get theoretical answers that may or may not prove to be accurate and useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure they're both relatively equal in performance since both are doing a sequence equal check. `SequenceEqual` doesn't do any magic - it still loops.

As for which one to use, go with `SequenceEqual` - it's built into the framework, other programmers already know it's functionality, and most importantly, there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This answer is good because it focuses on the practical impact over (likely) insignificant micro optimizations.

Comment: @poke yet, it does not answer. It says "your question is irrelevant". This cannot be assumed.

Comment: @usr No, the question is highly subjective anyway. Efficiency is not just “speed of execution” (not to mention that that’s also very dependent on the usage context). It’s also a lot “to what lengths do I have to go in order to make something faster”.

Comment: @poke true, but this answers neither of those. It's purely "don't even think about it".

Answer (score 3):

As `IList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I would believe that

```
a.SequenceEqual(b)
```

is a reasonable way to do the comparison, with the exentsion method being documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX).

Comment: _"Which is faster?"_ - _"You can use this one"_.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to compare to `List<T>` objects is to not go through interface dispatch by using `IList`. Instead, specialize the type to `List<T>`. The arguments should be `List<T>`.

This saves a lot of indirect calls. It's clearly faster than the `IEnumerable` based `SequenceEquals` while requires two indirect calls per element.

Also, you need to cache the count.

It would be best if `List<T>` had a built-in method, or implemented a certain interface or allowed access to its internal buffer. But none of that is available.

I guess the fastest possible way is to runtime-compile a function that returns you the internal buffers of each of those lists. Then, you can compare arrays which is much faster. Clearly, this relies on Full Trust and undocumented internals... Proceed with care.

There are also things you can do to avoid the cost of the comparer. It really depends on how important this issue is. You can go to great length to optimize this.

Comment: Interesting, are you saying that the abstract `IList<T>` standard **interface** is dedicated to the concrete `List<T>` **class**. If that was true, it would have been a quite weird BCL team decision. Also OP didn't say he's actually passing `List<T>`s. How about being `T[]` for instance.

Comment: @IvanStoev he says it in the title and in the text that it's a List<T>.

Comment: Hmm, didn't noticed that. I was just looking at the function signature, and people usually mess the two terms. Please take my apologies.